# Can the test client created from the WebApplicatoinFactory be shared between tests?

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core

I created some integration tests for ASP.NET using the WebApplicationFactory class from the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing package. The tests classes are running in parallel per the default XUnit behaviour. After I changed over 2 test classes to use WebApplicationFactory they ran fine and were quicker than the previous method we were using. However when I retrofitted all the test classes and tried it, the performance completely tanked and appeared to be hung in some kind of lock.

I noticed that call the factory.CreateClient() or factory.CreateDefaultClient() are very slow. Is there any option to setup a shared instance of the client and have all the tests use it? Not sure if that's possible or if it would be thread safe in a parallel situation.